# How could I kill processes/tasks running on particular port in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Thanks for looking into my quesry.

I am trying to kill all processes/tasks running on particular port on windows. For that, I am using the command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8083') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
```

But, it says TaskKill.exe /PID LISTENING
if I do netstat it says that
 TCP    0.0.0.0:8083           computername:0      LISTENING

I believe some service is still running on this port. Could you please guide me to kill all processes running on this port.

Thank you,
R Dama

Comment: my bad. i have missed /f at the end of command, to kill it forcibly.
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8083') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P /f